# Full Calendar, apply logic to defaultDate setting

Tags: javascript, calendar, fullcalendar

I've been learning Ruby over the last year and I'm very new to JS so I'll try to explain this as best I can.

I am using [Adam Shaw's full calendar plugin](http://fullcalendar.io/). The calendar displays events over a period specified by the user. 
I want to apply a bit of logic to the `defaultDate` setting that stipulates the following:

If the start month is greater than or equal to the current month then the default view should be the start month, not the current month. 
The same should apply if the start month is less than or equal to the current month.

(I realise this is all very verbose and crappy, but bear with me I'm learning)

```
var defaultDateLogic = function() {
  var finishDate = new Date("<%= finish.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S") %>");
  var startDate = new Date("<%= start.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S") %>");
  var todaysDate = new Date("<%= date_today.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S") %>");
  if (startDate >= todaysDate){
    startDate 
    // return this as default date
  } 
};
```

Then in my calendar settings I am calling this variable

```
defaultDate: defaultDateLogic,
weekMode: "liquid",
events: bookingEvents, // this can be a JSON feed (extra HTTP request)
header: headerOptions,
```

It seems using a function variable to set the default date is causing fullcalendar to crap out with this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'day' of undefinedfullcalendar.js?body=1:4614 Grid.extend.updateCellsfullcalendar.js?body=1:2869 fc.Grid.RowRenderer.extend.setRangefullcalendar.js?body=1:10018 fcViews.basic.View.extend.setRangefullcalendar.js?body=1:6644 fc.View.Class.extend.setDatefullcalendar.js?body=1:6817 fc.View.Class.extend.displayfullcalendar.js?body=1:7992 renderViewfullcalendar.js?body=1:7916 initialRenderfullcalendar.js?body=1:7880 renderfullcalendar.js?body=1:51 (anonymous function)jquery.js?body=1:385 jQuery.extend.eachjquery.js?body=1:137 jQuery.fn.jQuery.eachfullcalendar.js?body=1:30 $.fn.fullCalendarbookings:1737 setupCalendarjquery.js?body=1:3144 jQuery.Callbacks.firejquery.js?body=1:3256 jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWithjquery.js?body=1:3468 jQuery.extend.readyjquery.js?body=1:3499 completed
```

Why, and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the fullcalendar docs for [`defaultDate`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/defaultDate/) you can see that it takes a [`moment`](http://momentjs.com/). A moment is a type of date object, not a function.

*Some* fullcalendar options can take functions or objects and they are specified as such in the docs ([`selectOverlap`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/selectOverlap/) for example). But for defaultDate it needs a moment object.

[Momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) is another JS script that is required in order to run fullcalendar. It handles dates better than the standard JS date object. But you can keep your existing code because moment's constructor can parse a JS date.

So, all you need to do is pass a moment (or date) instead of a function.

Functions *are* objects in JS. And currently you are saying, "pass this function as an abject". Like if you were passing a **callback**.

```
defaultDate: defaultDateLogic,
```

Instead, you need to say, "run this function and then pass the returned object".

```
defaultDate: defaultDateLogic(),
```

Nice and simple.

Note:

This will only run one time (when fullcalendar is initialized). If you want it to run every time fullcalendar looks up its `defaultDate`... well you can't. This isn't supported by fullcalendar.

Comment: this is a brilliant answer. As well as an answer its given me a greater understanding of JS. Merci sir